# Regex optimization for Tag Extraction

Tags: regex

I am extracting the  tags and their surrounding text in the HTML source code. This is the Regex pattern that I use in my code:

```
String a_pattern = "(.*?)<a (.*?)</a>(.*)";
```

I tried to use "?" to make the quantifier lazy. However, this pattern takes lots of time while compiling a long string.

Can you please give me some hints on optimizing this pattern?

I should note that I need all three groups of text (before, within, and after )

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide inputs, expected and actual matches?

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea. Use a proper HTML parser instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: @p.s.w.g Is right, you should probably use a parser. But if you're set on using regex, tell us the language, and give us some examples of input and expected output. But a parser is probably your best bet in terms of runtime and code readability and just making it work in general

Comment: @sp00m, @p.s.w.g, @skamazin, thank you all for your comments. The point is that I don't need to only extract <a></a>. I know that I can do this using some parsers like jericho. In fact, having `Stackoverflow <a href> is a good website </a> for the beginners and <a> and also the experts </a>`, I expect to extract two strings: 1. Stackoverflow <a href> is a good website </a> for the beginners and,  2. for the beginners and <a> and also the experts </a>. In fact, the goal is to extracted the surrounding text of <a> tag. I am also programming in Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to get the content from those tags you can use this regex:

```
<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/lO4kU8/1)**

You can check the performance for both regex in this link:

**[Regex performance](http://jsperf.com/regex-optimize)**

As you can see, the regex you are using is 97% slower.

[image]

[image]

This result uses the javascript regex engine, but it is really useful to know regex performance.

Comment: Thank you Fede for your answer. What if I want to also extract the content before <a> and also after </a>?

Comment: @n4z4nin You can try using a complement regex, [check this] link(http://jsperf.com/regex-optimize/4). You can use multiple regex OR like: `(.*?)<a|<\/a>(.*)`. So, you could your two regex and even so it would be really faster than your current. Btw, if this answer your question you can consider mark it as resolved

Comment: Thank you Fede. However, I also need the text in between. That's why I am using three groups in my regex.

Comment: @n4z4nin Can you please check this one: http://regex101.com/r/lO4kU8/2. By the way, here you have the performance http://jsperf.com/regex-optimize/6. This one work very well 97% faster.

Comment: @n4z4nin The regex is `(.*?)<a|>(.*)<|>(.*)`